# xcode で iPhone アプリのビルド結果が lldb での実行になってしまう。

Tags: objective-c, xcode6

iPhoneアプリ開発を最近はじめました。

取り組んでる際、エラーも無くビルドは完了するのに、出力結果が(lldb)となってしまう現象に困っています。

具体例も載せず、分かりにくい質問ではありますが、ご教授お願い致します。

Comment: (lldb)の後にbtと入力して実行してみるとどうなるでしょうか？

Answer (score 1):

アプリを実行してiOSシミュレーターが起動または、実機でアプリの画面が出れば正常です。
(lldb)という表示はデバッガがコマンドを受付中であることを示していて、おそらくXcode上から起動しているためにデバッガにアタッチされている状態かと思います。
実機やシミュレーターから直接アプリをタップして起動してみれはデバッガをアタッチせずに起動できるはずです。
最近のXcodeはデフォルトでlldbというデバッガを使うので昔のgdbを使いたい場合はEditSchemeからデバッガをgdbに変更することで解消するはずです。

Answer (score 1):

Xcode4.xまではgdbとlldb両方入ってて、lldbがデフォルトで EditSchemeでgdbに変更できたんですが、Xcode6.xではgdbは標準で入ってないんで、gdbに変更することはできません。（問題解決になってなくてすみません。。。）